# binding key event to run the a href of an element

Tags: jquery

I have this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                          function liveeditor()
{ mywindow = window.open("/h8-html-editor", "LiveEditor", "toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=900px,height=900px");
mywindow.moveTo(15, 15);
}
   </script>
```

What I want to add is this I believe from jQuery Docs

```
$('#target').keydown(function() {
  alert('Handler for .keydown() called.');
});
```

How would I implement that to the code above? Would i create another code basically with the .keydown function with the mywindow = window.open code inside where the alert is?

Code I tried just not getting the event from the code I posted above of the `function liveeditor()`

```
$(function(){
   $(window).keydown(function(event){
  if (event.which == 67) {
       event.liveeditor();
    }
  if (event.which == 69) {
       event.colorpick();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: err... which key do you want to cause that function to run?  are you sure you don't mean click?

Comment: you want the `liveeditor` function to run every time a key is pressed?

Comment: i have two of these. I want liveeditor to be pushed when say E is pressed and colorpick to be opened when E is pressed I want the click func and the keypress func to run.

Comment: anyone with support? I've updated first post with another code I have tried to write.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking.  Maybe the answer is this?

```
$('#target').click(function() {
  liveeditor(); 
});
```

Comment: code I modify this to do say `window.keypress(e, function() {liveeditor();});`